# Area too thick with Subdiv

Tags: scripting, modifiers, vertices, subdivision-surface

I'm working on a dragon, building the base in Blender, and adding the details and textures with Mudbox. One issue I'm having though is the "hands" are is much larger and than it should be with the subdiv applied.

[image]
[image]

Is there any way I can fix this without applying the modifier and editing it by hand?

Edit:
Wireframe images

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello. Would you send an wireframe picture?

Comment: Sure thing. Added to the OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Edit mode, you can use the cut tool (K) with cut through (Z) to add a small loop around the center of the hand, like this :

[image: using the cut tool to add a loop]

After adding the loop, the center of the hand is no longer large (on the bottom, the hand with the loop cut and on the top a mirrored hand without a loop cut :

[image: render with and without the loop cut]

Comment: Thanks mate. Didn't realize it would've been so simple.